# Select ALL records with fieldvalue1 if any records (with fieldvalue1) have fieldvalue3 have a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to show all records for a specific value if ANY one of those records have another specific value. Essentially, if field3 = 'b', what is field1? Show all records with value of field1 regardless of their field3 value.

```
Record Number   External Id Letter
1            123456            a
2            123456            b
3            123456           c
4            456852           t
5            456852           b
```

record 2 has a letter value of 'b' - so I want to look at externalid, which is 123456, now I want to pull all records for external id regardless if the other records have a letter value of 'b'

Answer (score 3):

Use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
WHERE 
    t.letter = 'b'
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM mytable t1
        WHERE 
            t1.record_number != t.record_number 
            AND t1.external_id = t.external_id 
            AND t1.letter = 'b'
    )
```

Another option is to use a window function:

```
SELECT record_number, external_id, letter
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        MAX(CASE WHEN letter = 'b' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY external_id) mx
    FROM mytable t
) x WHERE mx = 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=240b5cd062d3306343681dadaabf1114)**:

```
record_number | external_id | letter
------------: | ----------: | :-----
            1 |      123456 | a     
            2 |      123456 | b     
            3 |      123456 | c     
            4 |      456852 | t     
            5 |      456852 | b
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`, but don't worry about filtering in the outer query:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.external_id = t.external_id and t2.letter = 'b'
             );
```

With an index on `(external_id, letter)`, I would expect this to have very good performance.